# Rewrite index page requests to a subdirectory and it's pages

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress, ubuntu-18.04

I have a XenForo forum, which powers the site. I also have a WordPress install in a subdirectory in XF. This is a must to get an addon called XPress to work so I can integrate both.

The issue is that there isn't a simple way to make the WP install /wp into the homepage. I have it half way working here:

```
    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /wp/ last;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
```

This "sort of" works. The homepage is now listing posts from /wp. However, that's about it.  Clicking on a post leads to /wp/ and returns a 404 on XF's side. Here's another attempt:

```
    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /wp/ last;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args /wp/index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
```

Which works well... if I wanted wordpress to control the site. If I click on a title, it goes to mydomain.com/ which is perfect, but the rest of the forum doesn't work.

So, I think what I want is this:

- For the root page only, rewrite to `/wp.`
- Maybe: rewrite `/wp/<title>` to `/<title>`
- Make sure `/wp/` rewrites to / if going to it but `/wp/wp-admin` still works.

Possible?

Comment: View profile, Network profile for contact info, tips, free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning of XenForo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the `location /` block into three:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /wp/ last;
}
location /wp/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this actually works well!

Comment: The only issue I see now is that clicking on a post now links to /wp/<title>. Is it possible to have it rewrite to just /<title>?

Comment: Actuallyy, what would it look like if I want to rewrite all requests from /wp/ to /?

Comment: You either want to host WordPress at `/wp/` or at `/`. If WordPress is hosted at the root, your other applications will need to be moved into subdirectories that can no longer be used as titles.